# Qual a diferença entre save e insert no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Qual diferença no [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) entre se inserir item com save e com insert ?

Exemplo:

```
db.pessoa.insert({"nome":"João"});
db.pessoa.save({"nome":"Maria"});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) sempre irá criar um novo documento enquanto o [save](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) atualiza um documento existente, ou insere um novo.

Se você executar somente a função save sem o parenteses no console do mongo `db.teste.save`, o código da função será mostrado, fica fácil de entender o que ela faz assim! Abaixo o código mostrado na console (mongod v3.4.2):

```
function (obj, opts) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw Error("can't save a null");

    if (typeof(obj) == "number" || typeof(obj) == "string")
        throw Error("can't save a number or string");

    if (typeof(obj._id) == "undefined") {
        obj._id = new ObjectId();
        return this.insert(obj, opts);
    } else {
        return this.update({_id: obj._id}, obj, Object.merge({upsert: true}, opts));
    }
}
```

Repassando o código:

- Um erro é lançado se o que você passar null, somente um número ou somente uma string.
- Se você passar um documento **sem _id preenchido**, ele é gerado e um **insert** é realizado.
- Se você **preencheu o _id**, um **update** com a opção `upsert: true` é realizado para **atualizar ou inserir** o documento.

Você consegue fazer a mesma coisa com o insert `db.teste.insert`. É uma função bem maior (não vou colar aqui). Confere o código dela, você verá que não tem verificação nenhuma para atualização do documento.