# Como editar um atributo no banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Estou *desenvolvendo* uma **API** onde eu quero **editar** *informações* de usuários *após* o **login**. Já consigo **pegar** as informações do usuário *após logar* como vocês podem ver na função:

**memberinfo**

```
apiRoutes.get('/memberinfo', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  console.log(token);
  if (token) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
    User.findOne({
      name: decoded.name
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
          return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Falha na autenticação!'});
        } else {
          res.json({success: true, msg: 'Bem vindo a area dos membros' + user.name + '!', user: user});
        }
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Nenhuma token foi enviada'});
  }
});
```

Gostaria de **manipular** essas informações e *salvar* no *banco*, como faço isso?
Como **por exemplo**, todo **USER** possui um `atributo` chamado `active` que é `boolean`, gostaria de *mudar* ele para `false` quando essa *função* **inactivate** for chamada, como faço para fazer o **update** do **USER** no banco?

```
apiRoutes.put('/inactivate', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
    User.findOne({
      name: decoded.name
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Falha na autenticação!'});
        } else {
          var UserUpdate = new User({
            active: false
          });
          UserUpdate.update(function(err){

          })

        }
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Nenhuma token foi enviada'});
  }
});
```

**USER** é um `model` do meu **banco**

```
var User = require('./app/models/user');
```

Comment: Veja [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224549/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-save-e-insert-no-mongodb/224551#224551) explicação. Você pode enviar o mesmo objeto e ao chamar o `save` do mongoose, se o documento tiver um `_id` ele atualiza o documento no mongo.

Comment: Neste caso eu tenho que passar um _id no momento do save, certo?

Comment: Nesse caso sim. De alguma forma é necessário identificar o documento na base, existem várias formas, como buscar o documento, alterar as propriedades desejadas e salvar depois, ou enviar o documento inteiro para o `save`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu compreendi o seu código, após a busca do usuário você pode editar a propriedade e salvar o documento novamente:

```
User.findOne({
      name: decoded.name
    }, function(err, user) {
        user.active = false;
        user.save(function() {
          res.status(200).send({success: true})
        });
```

Comment: Eu deveria usar um metodo get, put ou post para tal procedimento?

Comment: Partindo principio que vc deseja editar o usuário encontrado no `findOne`, pode ser post ou put Junior