# Inserções no mongo como fazer?

Tags: python, mongodb

Estou fazendo um programa que irá realizar inúmeras inserções no mongo(cerca de 500.000).
Porém percebi fazendo alguns testes, que quanto mais entradas no mongo eu tenho, mais demorado é a inserção.

Meu código:

```
def savePostRecommendation(uid, recs, db):
    temp = db.posts.find_one({'uid':uid})
    if(temp is None):
        db.posts.insert({'uid':uid,'recs':recs})
    else:
        db.posts.update({'uid':uid},{'uid':uid,'recs':recs})
```

Minha teoria:

Estou fazendo uma consulta para verificar se existe a entrada `temp = db.posts.find_one({'uid':uid})`, pois se a função fosse apenas db.posts.insert({'uid':uid,'recs':recs}), se o código fosse executado novamente haveria duas entradas no mongo com o mesmos valores. Então acho que quando mais entradas no mongo eu possuo essa busca que faço demora cada vez mais.

A minha pergunta é: Como faço para inserir no mongo um valor definindo meu atributo `uid` como uma chave primária como SQL faz. Para assim então eu inserir a entrada sem verificar se existe e que não haja `uids` duplicados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB não tem um tipo de auto-incremento como nos bancos de dados SQL, porém `_id` é algo muito especial para ele. O que você pode fazer é indicar qual é o `_id` manualmente:

```
db.posts.save({'_id':uid,'recs':recs});
```

Importante se atentar que esse valor seja sempre único (se ele for omitido, mongoDB irá criar o *hash* padrão). Voce pode economizar `if else` usando a expressao [save](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224549/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-save-e-insert-no-mongodb/224551#224551) que irá criar um novo ou atualizar se identificador já existir.